# want to display image url in contacts list

Tags: web-part, list-view, image-display

We are working on an iPad application with SharePoint 2010 as CMS.

On my SharePoint site we have a contacts list which the middleware is fetching using Lists.asmx and passing it to iPad.

Now what they want is, to display a url on iPad with each contact.  On clicking this url they will fetch the image of the corresponding contact.

So they want me to create a column in contacts list with name imageURL which will contain URL of actual images.  This is no big deal.

I can also store images in a library but the question is how I am supposed to link them(the URL and the Images).

Apart from this is it possible to display the images in the contacts list, I mean directly images flashing in front on names not urls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out this codeplex project to do just what you want:

http://spimagehyperlink.codeplex.com/

> A Sharepoint 2010 Custom Field Type that extends the SPUrlField type
>   to allow you to have an image instead of a text description as the
>   link.

In case you have not already seen the basic out of the box functionality for picture columns, there is also the out of the box "hyperlink or picture" column, which you can select Format Url as Picture